# problem with Enterprise Portal and Role Center installation

Tags: sharepoint-2007, center, axapta, role

I have installed the following:

.Net Framework 3.5, windows installer 3.1, IIS 7.0, ASP .NET, Microsoft DynamicsAX .NET business connector, AMO, AOS and Microsoft office share point server 2007

when trying to install Enterprise Portal and Role Center on office Sharepoint server I got a warning when the installation finished.

When trying to install Deploy ODC, I got an error. I think it is related to the fact I am missing the site: http://servername/sites/DynamicsAX

Now the questions:

1. How can I create the site/DynamicsAX site? (I saw in the Enterprise Portal and Role Centers on Office sharepoint server installation guide I need to configure it but couldn't find it in the actual setup)
2. Is this the reason I cannot fins the Enterprise portal when accessing AX?

Please assist if you have any idea?

Thanks,

Ub.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have the Enterprise Portal installation program create your site. But since the installation ended with a warning, you probably didn't get the site created.

Here is a link to information about how you can manually deploy ODC files: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2010/02/17/how-to-manually-deploy-odc-files-to-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2009-enterprise-portal.aspx